# Pragmas in python

Tags: python, pragma

I'm reading bottle.py source code. It's a web framework, with only 3000+ lines python code. So cool.

I found some code like this:

```
class ServerAdapter(object):
    quiet = False
    def __init__(self, host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, **config):
        self.options = config
        self.host = host
        self.port = int(port)

    def run(self, handler): # pragma: no cover
        pass
    ...
```

What does the `# pragma: no cover` mean? I can't find any introduce about the `pragma` syntax in the python documentations.

Comment: I believe it is a comment for pycoverage to tell it to skip that method

Comment: The `# pragma` is definitely nothing that directly works in Python. For Python, it is **only a comment**. There is nothing similar to say C preprocesor for that.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

It is apparenly related to the [coverage.py](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/):

> Coverage.py is a tool for measuring code coverage of Python programs. It monitors your program, noting which parts of the code have been executed, then analyzes the source to identify code that could have been executed but was not.

That exact `# pragma: no cover` is the hint that the part of code should be ignored by the tool -- see [Excluding code from coverage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/excluding.html) .

Answer (score 18):

For Python, it's simply a comment. It might be an annotation targeted at some external tool, which reads and analyzes Python code, similar, for example, to doctest's `#doctest: +ELLIPSIS` annotations or PyLint's `# pylint: disable=W0613` style annotations.